# ¿como puedo cambiar propiedades?

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría saber como puedo obtener mediante js el valor que tengo dentro del botón y condicionarlo para que me cambie el background de mi td, de antemano muchas gracias

```
<td id="cambio">
    <button type="button"  class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalcmcnc">
    <p id="cmcnc"><?php echo $mostrar['cmcnc']?></p>
    </button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalcmcnc" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Comentario CM CNC</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <?php echo $mostrar['comentario_cmcnc']?>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría de la siguiente forma, al oprimir el botón usando el evento click obtener el id del elemento td y cambiar su color, si lo que quieres es cambiar su color dependiendo de un valor, podrías colocar ese valor en un label que no sea visible para el usuario y utilizar ese valor en la función que llamas al oprimir el botón.

```
<button id="btn3" onclick="myFunction()">Dame click</button>
<h4 id="titulo">Cambio de color</h4>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var a = document.getElementById('titulo').style.color;
        if (a == 'yellow') { document.getElementById('titulo').style.color = 'black'; 
} else {
            document.getElementById('titulo').style.color = "yellow";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: busco algo mas con "onload" lo que pasa es que si asigno solamente un id no me cambia las lineas de mi tabla (se genera en php mediante un while), y pues estaba leyendo y aunque no entienda bien la estructura de javascript, se puede hacer con una funcion de onload y tomando valores de document.this o algo asi